# New-PSSession across domain boundaries

Tags: domain, powershell, credentials

I am trying to bring up a virtual machine that needs to be able to create new sessions (with New-PSSession). The highly engaging [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847850.aspx) is my constant companion, of course!

After bringing up a basic machine (Win 8.1 Enterprise):

- My company's primary domain is, say, `mycompany.com`.
- We have a development domain `dev.mycompany.com` so that developers have a sandbox to play with.
- I added the new VM (named my-vm) to the development domain `dev.mycompany.com`.
- I have a local account on the new VM, `my-vm\msorens` which is in the Administrators group on the local machine.

**First Hurdle:**

Attempting to run just `New-PSSession` failed with access denied because of cross-domain issues.
Per the troubleshooting page referenced above:

> When a user in another domain is a member of the Administrators group
>   on the local computer, the user cannot connect to the local computer
>   remotely with Administrator privileges.

I am not convinced this is true (due to my inexperience in domain issues) but applying the recipe for that remedy allowed the basic `New-PSSession` to work:

```
New-ItemProperty `
-Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy `
-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System `
-PropertyType DWord `
-Value 1
```

(And that, while less secure, is fine, as it is just a sandbox VM.)

**Second Hurdle:**

With the above patch in place I could successfully do any of these:

```
PS> New-PSSession
PS> New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost
PS> New-PSSession -ComputerName my-vm
```

However, my actual need is to give the FQDN of the machine:

```
PS> New-PSSession -ComputerName my-vm.dev.mycompany.com
```

That fails because of missing credentials. Which brings us to this:

```
PS> New-PSSession -ComputerName my-vm.dev.mycompany.com -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

I have tried my local (my-vm) credentials, which resulted in *WinRM cannot process the request; no logon servers available*.

I have tried my company domain credentials (note that is mycompany.com not the domain the VM is actually on dev.mycompany.com), which resulted in *Access is denied*.

**Is there a way to make this work?**

Comment: Have you tried specifying a UPN suffix? myuser@mydom.com

Comment: Does the `dev.mycompany.com` domain trust the `mycompany.com` domain? If not, you may not be able to connect. Also, we have an environment very similar to yours. My main corporate account is an Administrator on my VM, which is on our dev domain, and I'm able to log into the VM.

Answer (score 10):

At work we have the same situation. Here a some steps we do at new coworker computers so they are able to connect to these server how are outside our domain.

On client side

```
winrm quickconfig
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="Computer1,Computer2"}'
```

On server side

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
winrm quickconfig
```

For HTTPS

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname="_";CertificateThumbprint="_"}
```

For HTTP

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP
```

Test with

```
Test-WsMan ComputerName
Test-WsMan ComputerName -UseSSL
```

Create a session with

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName Computer1 -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Of course you need to configure your firewall to let the server listen on the powershell remoting port.

**Edit: Set TrustedHosts with PowerShell**

Or with PowerShell (as Admin)

```
Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "Computer1,Computer2"
```

And check (don't need Admin for that)

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
```

Comment: Or, instead of a New-PSSession, you can just do an Enter-PSSession. Also, I only this line - winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="Computer1"}' - since I had remoting working intra-domain from before.